# In my python program how do I count the number of times a value has occurred

Tags: python

#### My code:

I made some code that prints 100 random values from a range 1-8, and if the number is from 1-5 it prints and x next to it and if it 6-8 it prints a y. I'm wondering how I can print the number of times an x is printed and a y is printed.

I'm also wondering why i had to make a conditional statement for every individual value i wanted to print x for, instead of just writing this (which didn't work properly)

Comment: Updated answer below. Also doing `num == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5` translates to 5 different conditions of which the last 4 are always truthy since 2, 3, 4, 5 are not equal to any of the following values: 0, None, False. '', [], {}, (). It's not equivalent to `num == 1 or num == 2 or num == 3...` etc. You can do `num in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` or you can do what i did below `1 <= n <= 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put x and y in a dictionary and increment every time in the loop, the frequency they occur:

```
import random

numbers = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}


def randomnumbers():
    for x in range(100):
        n = random.randint(1, 8)

        if 1 <= n <= 5:
            numbers['x'] += 1
            print('%dx' % n)
            # E.g. 1x
        elif 6 <= n <= 8:
            numbers['y'] += 1
            print('%dy' % n)
            # E.g. 7y


randomnumbers()
print('x %d times' % numbers['x'])
# E.g. x 61 times
print('y %d times' % numbers['y'])
# E.g. y 39 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 variables to remember how many times x and y is printed.

```
import random

howManyX = 0 # how many times x is printed
howManyY = 0 # how many times y is printed

def randomnumbers():
    for i in range(100):
       num = random.randint(1, 8)

       # if your number is from range 1 - 5: print x and increment howManyX
       if 1 <= num <= 5:
           print(num, 'x')
           howManyX += 1
       # if your variable is not from range 1 - 5 (in this case it is 6, 7 or 8): print y and increment howManyY
       else:
           print(num, 'y')
           howManyY += 1  

randomnumbers()
#now you can print how many times have x and y occurred
print(howManyX, howManyY)
```